# What does "struct{...} x, y, z;" mean?

Tags: c

What does `struct{...} x, y, z;` mean in C programming language?

Related article:

[Article](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1iXv.png)

Could you please give examples about it.

```
struct {int a;} x, y;
int main()
{
x.a=0;
y.a=1;
return 0;
}
```

There is no error.

```
struct {...} x, y;
int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

but there is an error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '...' token.

Comment: You know what `struct{...} x;` means, right? Your declaration simply adds  `y` and `z` to it.

Comment: The article seems to explain it pretty clearly. What part of it is unclear?

Comment: My English is not good enough to understand it well. Could you please simplify it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I don't know what `struct{...} x;` means. What does it mean?

Comment: @U.AL It's a declaration of variable `x`. The type of the variable `x` is `struct{...}`.

Comment: The `...` part is a simplification of "some other stuff goes here", and not valid C or C++ syntax. You have to specify the content of a `struct`, and three dots is not a valid declaration here. This is the reason for the compiler error.

Comment: @MatsPetersson thank you, now I understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well these are anonymous structures. And you are declaring those variables `x`,`y` and `z` which are of that structure type. You can't pass it to other function though. So either you will keep these as global or static variables and use it accordingly. That's all you can do.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct{...} x, y, z;
```

Are the three variables of the same anonymous type. Equivalent below, except that the type S is not anonymous.

```
struct S{...};

struct S x;
struct S y;
struct S y;
```

BTW the article explains it in the next text lines.

Answer (score 1):

It means to create the variables of that structure type.
it will create 3 variables namely x,y,z of your Structure type